# How to get Active Directory public folder info about EWS public folders

Tags: c#, active-directory, exchangewebservices

Using EWS (in Visual Studio) I can find all the Public Folder root folders and sub folders in Exchange. But I don't know how to get information from Active Directory about the folders. There doesn't seem to be an ID or GUID field that is shared between EWS and Active Directory for each folder.

Can someone please tell me how I can find a public folder in AD using the values returned by EWS?

Thank you